# Azure Function with serviceBusTrigger stops receiving messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have am Azure Function configured with a `servieBusTrigger` to receive messages from a topic subscription on Azure Serivce Bus. The function have been running fine for days, but this morning I noticed a lot of messages on the subscription. It turns out, that my Function no longer receives messages from the queue.

I've checked the queue to ensure that the messages are not in the dead letter queue. They are not. I have logging in place in my Function and no log statements are found (which I didn't expect since the messages are never processed). I've checked the log files on Kudu (`LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\MyFunction). It is empty and I did enable application logging through the Portal.

Here's my `function.json`:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "tasks-v1",
      "subscriptionName": "errormail-v1",
      "connection": "connection",
      "accessRights": "Manage"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I wrote earlier, the Function did work fine for days. I'm running on the consumption plan, why always on shouldn't be an issue.

Any ideas to how to debug this?

UPDATE: For future reference, we updated to compiled functions which fixes the problem (which makes sense since the bug are in Roslyn).

Comment: Do you see any incriminating host logs? LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host

Also, happy to investigate if you follow the steps here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: No errors in host logs. I'll check out the link. Thanks.

Comment: Does it start working again if you go to the Function Portal? There is a category of issues that cause such behavior, so knowing this is useful to isolate.

Comment: I think it's too late to check chat. I disabled the function when it wasn't working. When I enabled it (after seeing your message) everything runs again. But for how long :( I read about the problems you are referring to. But wasn't that related to being on the app service plan?

Comment: @MattMason-MSFT Here's the info from the log: 2017-03-30T05:27:13.259 Function started (Id=49af748b-5c38-4527-998e-50e9f5309304). The function is in West US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your function ran into this bug with roslyn compilation which is solved via restart: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/999

I saw this error in your function app logs:

> 2017-03-28 23:14:11.6306121 Cannot enqueue data after PromiseNotToEnqueue.

This is a sporadic issue, but if you want a workaround you can use [precompiled functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions).

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. Were planning to port to precompiled anyway.